# Removing decimal point in character string in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a character coding system in excel below is an example. What I want is to remove the decimal point (note that the decimal points are placed at differenr location and some without any decimal point).

The first column is what I have while the second column is what I desire.

Thanks

```
Code    Desire
AA1.50  AA150
BB2.44  BB244
B11.36  B1136
CC1.98  CC198
CC1.4   CC14
CCC     CCC
D00.0   D000
Z00.1   Z001
A00.9   A009
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the value you want to change is in cell A1, your code is:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")
```

Or, if you want to do a bulk replace, highlight the column(s) with the data you want to change, press **Ctrl + H**, put "**.**" (just the period, no quotation marks) in the **Find what** field, leave the **Replace with** field blank, and hit **Replace All**.